# Multiple Face Detection

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I have a code in OpenCV (in C++) which uses "haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml" to detect upper body. 
It detects single upper body. How can I make it detect multiple upper bodies.
I think  CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT is detecting only the biggest object. But I am not knowing how to solve this issue

The code goes like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
CascadeClassifier body_cascade;
body_cascade.load("haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml");

VideoCapture captureDevice;
captureDevice.open(0);

Mat captureFrame;
Mat grayscaleFrame;

namedWindow("outputCapture", 1);

//create a loop to capture and find faces
while(true)
{
    //capture a new image frame
    captureDevice>>captureFrame;

    //convert captured image to gray scale and equalize
    cvtColor(captureFrame, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);

    //create a vector array to store the face found
    std::vector<Rect> bodies;

    //find faces and store them in the vector array
    body_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3,                                                                                                                                     
    CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30,30));    
    //draw a rectangle for all found faces in the vector array on the original image
    for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Point pt1(bodies[i].x + bodies[i].width, bodies[i].y + bodies[i].height);
        Point pt2(bodies[i].x, bodies[i].y);

        rectangle(captureFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }

    //print the output
    imshow("outputCapture", captureFrame);

    //pause for 33ms
    waitKey(33);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is some inconsistency in your code, since `face_cascade` is not defined anywhere, but I assume its type is `CascadeClassifier`.
`detectMultiScale` stores all detected objects in the `faces` vector. Are you sure it contains only one object?
Try removing the `CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT` flag, because you want all objects to be detected, and not only the biggest one.
Also, make sure you set the `minSize` and `maxSize` parameters correctly (see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)), since those parameters determine the minimal and maximal detectable object sizes.