# how to detect multiple faces in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having problem with detecting multiple faces at a time.the following code  detect a frontal face and eyes for one person only.I tried to make it work for all available faces but i can't...please help

```
  CvCapture* capture;
    Mat frame;
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    Mat frame;
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;

    face_cascade.load( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"; );
    eyes_cascade.load(  "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml"; );


   capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );

  frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
  cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;    
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
     {
       Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
       int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
       circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
     }
  }

  imshow( "window", frame );
```

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320093/multiple-face-detection

Comment: yes i've checked it allready and doesn't work

Comment: detection and drawing works ok, and detects multiple faces. I don't see in your code where you are grabbing the capture frames.

Comment: you probably need `cvQueryFrame` inside a loop...

Comment: sorry i must hv skipped it when i copied my code.i 'd just edited it

Comment: Yes, my comment on the loop is on your last edit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basically your code (just changed to load a single fixed image and removed the `equalizeHist` call) gives me those results:

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

so your code basically does what it should do. Your problem seems to be in your image data or parameters regarding your image data. Post sample images please.

Just for you to be sure  that I didn't change big parts of the code, I used:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/MultiLena.png");

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(input,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);


    //CvCapture* capture;
    //Mat frame;
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    Mat frame;
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;

    face_cascade.load( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" );
    eyes_cascade.load(  "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml" );


   //capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );

  //frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
  //cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  //equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

    frame_gray = gray;
    frame = input;


  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;    
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
     {
       Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
       int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
       circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
     }
  }

  imshow( "window", frame );


  cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/multiFaces.png", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for some reasons i didn't understand it works for your sample image.thanks!!

Comment: I found the generated xml files here and they work well. https://github.com/AlexeyAB/OpenCV-detection-models/tree/master/haarcascades

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could implement the following strategy:

- Detect the first face, it will generate a rect.
- Create a new Mat without that rect.
- Analyze the new mat and generate a new face detection rect.
- Now draw both rects into a video capture stream.

Keep in mind to display on screen only the background video stream with selected rects, so the system remains efficient.

Comment: Simply **NO**. The classifier already handles multiple detections. BTW, how do you plan to handle the _removed_ part?